# using document.getElementById to get input values in the url

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, thickbox

Below is my code.

```
<input type="submit" class="thickbox btn btn-large btn-darkbrown" value="Prüfen" onclick="tb_show('https://ibe.dirs21.de/Channels/bayers-hotel/default.aspx?anreise='+document.getElementById('anreise').value+'&abreise='+document.getElementById('abreise').value+'&adults='+document.getElementById('adults').value+'&children=1'+document.getElementById('children').value+'&TB_iframe=true&height=800&width=800&modal=true')"
```

Issue:- If i click on submit, then the thickbox shows the same site and not the url.

Comment: What does "tb_show" do?

Comment: This function is defined inside the thickbox.js file. I removed the class "thickbox" and now i see the function doesn't work...

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/gppvaojh/

Comment: Thank you! I think the Problem is that the javascript code from thickbox.js brokes if i use character like '

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code now to this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-darkbrown" value="Prüfen" onclick="tb_show('Zimmer','https://ibe.dirs21.de/Channels/bayers-hotel/default.aspxTB_iframe=true&height=800&width=800')">
```

It works, but how can i integrate the Values from the inputfields now?